# Installation error on Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to launch laravel which is locally hosted on my browser but it gives me the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/larawiz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475

How can I correct this?

Comment: And what ist _on line 475_?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is your version of PHP which I believe you may be using PHP 5.5.

Laravel 5.3 uses the splat operator which is only available in PHP version 5.6

The line you're referring to is : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L475

Which is outlined as part of 5.6 here:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Simply put, you either need to upgrade your version of PHP or move back to Lavavel 5.1 which I believe still supports PHP 5.5

Laravel 5.1 Requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation (PHP >= 5.5.9)

Laravel 5.3 Requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation (PHP >= 5.6.4)

Comment: Hi @James I have same problem with php v7. The error log refers to this line  `function event(...$args)` in `helpers.php`. The reason why OP had error was due to `splat operator` that was introduced in php 5.6 , but I m using php v7 still getting this error and I dont see any deprecation here http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your code is running through the PHP7 interpreter and you don't have any other interpreters running?

If you do `php --version` what do you get?

Comment: Hi @James yeah it was showing v7 when I checked. I cant post the log now, as I have downgraded to 5.6 after wasting too much time.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it was the same line and error? It may have been another issue because PHP 7 shouldn't be throwing unexpected operators for splat operator.