# Laravel 5.3 is giving an error on production server while working fine on localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, php-5.6

**Laravel 5.3** is giving an error on production server while working fine on localhost. Other than changing php version, is there any other possible solution?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/html/laravel_fresh/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 475

Comment: This post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39486346/4584028

Comment: I have checked this out. It is been mentioned in question other than changing php version and the post you mentioned gives exact same answer of changing php version on hosted server

Comment: Please provide more information to make this question helpfull for other users.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You need to have at least PHP >= 5.6.4 in order to run Laravel 5.3.